# Vuetify - dynamically create a form with v-text-fields + CRUD - v-model issue

Tags: vuetify.js

in a Vuetify project I would like to dynamically create all the required fields to perform CRUD Actions:
I prepared a working sample here:

https://codepen.io/jslab-it/pen/KKqyBdX

Everything's working not bad, but when I click on the edit button, the dialog appears but fields are not populated:
I assume that problem is that v-model is "calculated":

```
:v-model="'editedItem.'+f.name"
```

in fact in the last field that is not generated but hardcoded and thus has

```
v-model="editedItem.calories"
```

the field is automatically populated.

I tried also using a computer property for `editedItem`, but without success

Can suggest if it is possible and the right path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `editedItem[f.name]`, which is a standard way to access dynamic property in js.

Comment: you're fully right!
what a shame!! :-(